# is there any way to convert video to image using php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, image, video-capture, video-conversion

i want to display a 360 video en screen, like this example 
https://scaleflex.github.io/js-cloudimage-360-view/

i have an idea to shoot a video  and convert it to image, for every second a frame will capture from the video ,and the names must be named by numbers,but i need to convert image to video.

is there any plugin helps to convert video to images and store it in local machine
or an example or documentation can help me to do that?

thanks

Comment: you can use ffmpeg

Comment: take a look at `ffMpeg` - it is very powerful so with some skilled coding you can probably do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-extract-frames
you can convert the video into frames using this **ffmpeg-extract-frames** package in JavaScript

Comment: thank you, but how can i impplemented in laravel?????